# $\forall x\in X,\exists(x\in)U\subset X$ s.t. $\overline{U}$ is compact, $\iff$ $\forall x\in X,U\subset X,\exists V$ s.t. $\overline{V}$ is compact

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space. Show that the following statements are equivalent:

- $\forall x\in X,\exists(x\in)U\subset X$ such that $\overline{U}$ is compact.
- $\forall x\in X,x\in U\subset X,\exists V$ such that $\overline{V}\subset U$   is compact.

I am quite clueless here. I know that if, given $x\in X$ and $x\in U\subset X$, if the first statement holds, then there has to be $V$ neighborhood of $x$ such that $\overline{V}$ is compact. Whether $\overline{V}\subset U$, $U\subset \overline V$, or $V\setminus U\ne \emptyset$, I only have $\overline{V}\cap U$ to look at. as the required set. But I still feel like I am merely making a non-profound guess, and I can't quite see the relevance of $X$ being Hausdorff to the process I attempted. Could you expand my horizons in that topic?

Comment: What is the relationship between $x$ and $U$ in the second statement?

Comment: That is a neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: Is it obvious for you that the second statement implies trivially the first? Simply put $U=X$.

Comment: It is, but the converse I find a little not clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now first I will claim the following is true for $X$

> For a compact set $K$ and a point $x\notin K$ there exists neighborhood $U_x$ and $V_K$ such that $U_x\cap V_K=\emptyset$

Since $X$ is Hausdorff, for each $y\in K$ we can find two disjoint neighborhoods $B_y$ and $B_x(y)$ such that $B_x\cap B_y=\emptyset$. $\{B_y\}$ is open covering of $K$ thus $\{B_{y_1},\dots B_{y_n}\}$ is a finite subcover for $K$. Set $U_x=\cap_{i} B_x (y_i)$ and $V_K=\cup_i B_{y_i}$. It is easy to show that $U_x\cap V_K=\emptyset$

Now suppose $x\in X$ and $U_x\subset X$. By the first statement there exists $W_x$ such that $\bar{W}$ compact. Take $T=U\cap W$ and consider the set $\partial T$ of boundary points of $T$. This set is closed and contained in $\bar{T}\subset \bar{W}$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff this implies that $\partial T$ is compact.

Now  I claim that

> There exists $V_x$ such that $\bar{V}\subset \partial T$

Since $\partial T$ is compact by the first result we can find disjoint neighborhoods $N$ of $x$ and $M$ of $\partial T$.This implies $\bar{N}\cap \partial T=\emptyset$. Let $V=T\cap N$. Then

$$
\bar{V}\subset \bar{T}\cap \bar{N}=(T\cup \partial T)\cap \bar{N}=T\cap\bar{N}\subset T
$$

Then the claim follows.

Comment: Can you explain why is this compactness not derived only by the fact that $T$ is bounded and $\partial{T}$ is closed?

Comment: It is up to the cover as I reckon, excuse me for this.

Comment: Would you help me, however, understand the reason for it being compact as a result ?

Comment: @Meitar: In a Hausdorff topological space, every closed subset of a compact set is closed. Since $\bar{W}$ compact and $\partial T$ closed the result follows.

Comment: Do you mean, closed subset=compact?

Comment: Closed subset of a compact set is compact.

Comment: Why should $V_x\subset \partial T$? 
How is it infered?

Comment: I showed that $\bar{V}\subset T$, but every set is a subset of its closure. So $V\subset \bar{V}\subset T$.

Comment: But this was your claim, with the boundary, I neither understand why it is true, nor do I see why it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In Hausdorff spaces the following holds: Let $K_1, K_2$ be compact sets, then there exist open sets $U_1, U_2$ such that $K_1\subseteq U_1, K_2\subseteq U_2$ and $U_1\cap U_2=\emptyset$.

Apply this to the sets $\{x\}, \partial U$ to show that the first statement implies the second.

Remark: The Hausdorff property is crucial as it gives you the nice separation above. The following example might be instructive: Endow ${x, y} with the topology

$$ \{  \{x\}, \{x,y\} \}.$$

Can you find a $U$ such that the second statement fails?

Comment: I don't quite understand why I can't say that the exists $V$ such that $\overline{V}\subset X$ is compact, by first statement, then take $\overline{V}\cap U$ for a random $U$ containing $X$. Where is the failure here? Why do we need to use seperations?

Comment: You would need to prove then, that $\overline{\overline{V}\cap U}\subseteq U$.

Answer (score 1):

1.0. Let $U$ be a nbhd of $x.$ Let $U'$ be a nbhd of $x$  such that $$A=Cl_X( U')$$ is compact.Let $U''=U\cap U'$ and let $U'''$ be open in $X$ with $x\in U'''\subset U''.$

1.1.  $U'''$ is open in $X$ so it is open in the subspace $A$.

1.2.   Key point: Any compact Hausdorff space is a regular space. We have $x\in U'''$ where $U'''$ is open in $A.$ By regularity of $A$ there exists $V,$ open in $A,$ such that  $$x\in V\subset  Cl_A(V)\subset U'''.$$ 1.3. Since $V$ is open in $A$ and   $V\subset U'''\subset A$ with $U'''$ open in $X$,  we know that $V$ is open  in $X.$

1.4 .  $Cl_A(V)=Cl_X(V)$ (because $A$ is closed in $X$) and it is compact, because it  is closed in the compact  Hausdorff space $A$.

1.5. Putting all this together we have $$x\in V\subset Cl_X(V)\subset U,$$ where  $V$ is open in $X,$ and $Cl_X(V )$ is compact.

2.0. For the reverse implication, if $U$ is a nbhd of $x$ and there exists a nbhd $V$ of $X$ such that $\overline V$ is compact and  $x\in V\subset \overline V\subset U,$ then to find a nbhd $U'$ of $x$ such that $\overline {U'}$ is compact,let $U'=V.$ If you are confused here then change $U$ in your first displayed line to $U'$.

Remark. More strongly than the "key point" (1.2): A compact Hausdorff space is a  normal space.